# Prestashop 1.7 Breadcrumb titles

Tags: prestashop-1.7, breadcrumbs

I am trying to edit the breadcrumbs in a custom Prestashop theme that I am making based on the Classic theme in version 1.7.6.8. The website I am working on has Prestashop located in a folder at mydomain.com/shop, so I would like the breadcrumbs to read:

Home / Shop / Products

Where *Home* links to mydomain.com and *Shop* goes to mydomain.com/shop.

I have added the link for Home to mydomain.com ok. Now I want to change the default Prestashop breadcrumbs because it currently reads:

Home / Home / Products

The second home goes to the right link (mydomain.com/shop) but I don't know how to change it to read *Shop* instead of *Home*. I have found a way to edit the controllers so as to remove the second home link, this would allow me to just add a new link with Shop next to the new Home link that I already added, however this doesn't seem like a very elegant solution and will require altering the script on lots of pages. Surely there must be a better way?

Thanks for any feedback.

Edit: Here is the code from controllers/productController.php

```
    public function getBreadcrumbLinks()
{
    /*$breadcrumb = parent::getBreadcrumbLinks();*/

    $categoryDefault = new Category($this->product->id_category_default, $this->context->language->id);

    foreach ($categoryDefault->getAllParents() as $category) {
        if ($category->id_parent != 0 && !$category->is_root_category) {
            $breadcrumb['links'][] = $this->getCategoryPath($category);
        }
    }

    if (!$categoryDefault->is_root_category) {
        $breadcrumb['links'][] = $this->getCategoryPath($categoryDefault);
    }

    /*$breadcrumb['links'][] = array(
        'title' => $this->product->name,
        'url' => $this->context->link->getProductLink($this->product, null, null, null, null, null, (int) $this->getIdProductAttributeByRequest()),
    );*/

    return $breadcrumb;
}
```

You can see the two sections I have removed, the first removes the default "Home" link, the second removes the link with the product name that I do not need. Obviously the code goes somewhere to look up the link and matches it to a name, I just don't know where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, you can change the tag from "Home" to "Shop" by altering the files in shoproot/var/cache/prod/translations/catalogue.[your language].php

There are a number of places where "Home" appears in the file, to change the breadcrumb it is around line 6370 in the en-gb version.

EDIT: Here is a better option, from your Prestashop control panel you can go to international, translations, modify translations. From the drop downs select theme translation, the theme you are working on, the language, click modify, search for "home" and then put the translation as "shop". This saves you having to make the change to the cached file if you have to clear the cache from the control panel.